# Maven2 compiles my tests, but doesn't run them

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a simple Maven2 project with tests written for TestNG. When I say `mvn test` Maven2 compiles my test, but don't run them. I already checked this page: http://maven.apache.org/general.html#test-property-name. This is not my case.

Anybody can help?

My directory structure:

```
pom.xml
src
  main
    java
      com ...
  test
    java
      com ...
target
  classes <— .class files go there
  test-classes <— .class files with tests go there
```

This is what I see if I run `mvn -X test` (end of the log):

```
...
[INFO] Surefire report directory: <mydir>/target/surefire-reports
Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd <mydir> && /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java -jar /var/folders/+j/+jAx0g2xGA8-Ns9lWNOWgk+++TM/-Tmp-/surefirebooter7645642850235508331.jar /var/folders/+j/+jAx0g2xGA8-Ns9lWNOWgk+++TM/-Tmp-/surefire4544000548243268568tmp /var/folders/+j/+jAx0g2xGA8-Ns9lWNOWgk+++TM/-Tmp-/surefire7481499683857473873tmp

-------------------------------------------------------
  T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.191 sec
```

I have two tests in the project (`MainTest.java` and `FileSetTest.java`).

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.SKIP</groupId>
    <artifactId>SKIP</artifactId>
    <name>SKIP</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>http://www.SKIP.com</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>jsr14</target>
                    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.SKIP.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do your test classes start or end with *Test*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "problem" is somehow related to the fact that you are compiling your tests using the jsr14 target mode which causes the compiler to emit JDK 1.4-compatible bytecode so I think that annotations are removed and TestNG doesn't detect anything to run.

My suggestion would be to configure the maven-compiler-plugin to use different compliance level when compiling code code from main and test as shown below:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>jsr14</target>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test-compile</id>
      <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I did a quick test, it seems to work.